# If $z_1=1-i$, $z_2=-2+4i$ and $a+ib=…$

Tags: complex-numbers

If $z_1=1-i$, $z_2=-2+4i$ and $a+ib=\dfrac {z_1.z_2}{{z_1}^{'}}$ then the values of $a$ and $b$ are :
$$a. 2,-4$$
$$b. 4, \dfrac {5}{2}$$
$$c. 1, 0$$
$$d. 4, \dfrac {1}{2}$$

My Attempt ;
$$a+ib=\dfrac {(1-i)(-2+4i)}{(1+I)}$$
$$=\dfrac {2+6i}{1+i}$$
$$=\dfrac {8+4i}{2}$$
$$=4+2i $$
On comparing, we have :
$$a=4, b=2$$

Comment: How did you go about the question? What have you tried?

Comment: @Crosby, please find the edited version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $z_1'$ means $\overline{z_1}$, then your answer is correct: the quotient is indeed $4+2i$.